# change favicon icon in odoo

Tags: xml, odoo-13

In Odoo version 13 I'm changing favicon icon in the browser tab,
it works fine, but when I open website it gives me this error.

```
ValueError: Element '<xpath expr="//head/link[last()]">' cannot be located in parent view
```

it comes from a template which is already defined in **web/views/webclient_templates.xml**
how can fix this.
here is my code.

```
<template id="my_module.web_layout" inherit_id="web.layout">
        <xpath expr="//link[@rel='shortcut icon']" position="after">
            <t t-set="favicon" t-value="request.env['ir.config_parameter'].get_param('my_module.favicon_url', '').strip()"/>
            <t t-if="favicon">
                <link rel="shortcut icon" t-att-href="favicon" type="image/x-icon"/>
            </t>
        </xpath>
</template>
```

Comment: Are you planing to change the website favicon or default Odoo fevicon ?

Comment: any update on this? I'm still facing this issue in Odoo 14.

Comment: Don't know, I'm not working on odoo anymore since 8 months. Try once once asking on odoo official forum.